# changing a key name with a variable and not the value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, var

```
var obj = {id: {bike: {coords: {latitude: 1,longitude: 2},orientation: 5, timestamp: 7}}};  

   obj[id] = mapId;
   alert([1].obj);
   obj.id.bike.coords.latitude = lat;
   obj.id.bike.coords.longitude = lng;
   obj.id.bike.orientation = ori;
   obj.id.bike.timestamp = 50;
```

I im having a serious problem I would like to change the key instead of the value for, example I want to change id into a number and bike into Yamaha im passing variables using a php to java script.

```
var mapId = "<?php echo $mapId ?>"; 
var bike = "<?php echo $bike ?>"; // 
var lat = "<?php echo $lat ?>"; //
var lng = "<?php echo $lng ?>";
var ori = "<?php echo $ori ?>"; //
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? I think it's not possible?

Comment: i want to do this the easy way possible i just want to make a array set up like this using variables.